# If $L$ is a positive semi-definite matrix and all elements in each row add up to 0, How to prove that the inf-norm of $(I+L)(I+L+L^2)^{-1} \leq 1$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-norms, condition-number

Assuming that the L is a positive semi-definite matrix and
$$ \sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} L_{i,j} = 0. \quad for \;  i = 1,...,N.$$
I want to prove that $\|(I+L) (I+L+L^2)^{-1}\|_{\infty} \leq 1$, I have founded the proof of $\|(I+L)^{-1}\|_{\infty} \leq 1$ requires an additional diagonal dominance condition.

I have try to prove the $\|(I+L)^{-1}\|_{\infty} \leq 1$ by Diagonalization,i.e, there exists an invertible matrix, denoted as P, such that: $L=P^{-1} \Lambda P, \Lambda = diag(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_N)$ and $\lambda_i \geq 0$. So I can rewrite $(I+L)^{-1} = (I + P^{-1} \Lambda P  )^{-1}=(P^{-1}(I + \Lambda) P)^{-1} = P^{-1} (I+\Lambda)^{-1} P$, consequently, $\|(I+L)^{-1}\|_{\infty} \leq \|P^{-1}\|_{\infty} \|(I+\Lambda)^{-1}\|_{\infty}\|P\|_{\infty} \leq\|P^{-1}\|_{\infty} \|P\|_{\infty} \leq 1$. This proof process does not seem to require that L is diagonally dominant, am I missing any steps? Whether it is eventually less than $1$ will be determined by the condition number of P, and it can be easily extended to proof $\left\|(I+L)(I+L+L^2)^{-1}\right\|_{\infty} \leq 1$?

Is there a theory about the matrix P composed of eigenvectors that can demonstrate it? If the infinity norm cannot be proven, can the 2-norm be proven? I would be very grateful if you could provide a reference to the proof of this claim.

**EDIT 1:** The last step $\|P^{-1}\| \|P\| \leq 1$ does not hold for inf-norm but holds for 2-norm. Is there any ways could proof it for the case of inf-norm?

Comment: How can you divide by a matrix?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo A/B equal A*B^{-1}. Sorry, I didn't write it clearly

Comment: Then please update the question

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I have update the question, thx u for the correction!

Comment: @user1551 yes, I found this phenomenon when I conducted numerical experiments, and now I want to prove it theoretically

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Thank you for your answer. I have updated my question to include a condition where the sum of each row of the matrix is zero. I think my proof procedure is correct for 2-norm for the reason that P is a Orthogonal matrix. However, finding a solution for the inf norm seems challenging, and I haven't been able to proof it

Comment: @user1551 thx u for your answer, I have updated my question to include a condition where the sum of each row of the matrix is zero.

Comment: @OwenJun Oh please. Run a computer experiment before you ask. It is easy to generate a random counterexample. E.g. let
$$
Q=\pmatrix{a&a&a\\ a&b+1&b\\ a&b&b+1},\quad\Lambda=\pmatrix{0\\ &0.1\\ &&0.01}
$$
where $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $b=\frac{-1}{n-\sqrt{n}}$. Since $Q(1,1,\ldots,1)^T=(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$ and $Q=Q^T=Q^{-1}$, if we put $L=Q\Lambda Q$, then $L$ is PSD with zero row/column sums. However, numerically we have $\|(I+L)(I+L+L^2)^{-1}\|_\infty=1.0021$.

Comment: @user1551 Yes, you're right. The Julia implementation of `norm` treats the matrix as a vector.

Comment: @user1551 thx u for your comment, I have do many computer experiements and not found counterexample. and is the $Q=Q^{-1}$ holds for your example?

Comment: @OwenJun As already mentioned in my previous comment, we have $Q=Q^T=Q^{-1}$. (Here $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $b=\frac{-1}{3-\sqrt{3}}$.) The $Q$ I used is a reflection matrix. It is symmetric and orthogonal.

Comment: @user1551 thx u very much for your answer,  your comments addressed my concerns, but I would like to ask further if my proof process holds for the 2-norm?

Comment: @OwenJun The inequality is true when the induced $2$-norm (aka spectral norm) is used. Since $0\prec I+L\preceq I+L+L^2$, we have $0\prec (I+L)(I+L+L^2)^{-1}\preceq I$. Hence $\|(I+L)(I+L+L^2)^{-1}\|_2\le1$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ means the spectral norm, then it is equivalent to prove that $\sigma_{min}$ of the inverse is no less than $1$, but this is somehow clear since the inverse is simply
$$(I+L+L^2)(I+L)^{-1}=I+L^2(I+L)^{-1},$$
and by diagonalizing $L$ or writing it into norm form we can see that $L^2(I+L)^{-1}$ is still positive semi-definte.

Comment: Are you proving or disproving the statement? Also, the OP clearly asks for the infinity norm.

Comment: OK, so now I get that the OP is probably talking about $\ell^{\infty}\to\ell^{\infty}$ norms, then I don't have an immediate insight.